# creating setup.exe

Tags: installation

I have three exe files, and a folder which is used to install programs, I am thinking of doing a setup which run these exe and then move a folder to c:.

Program execution will be like this:

file1.exe

file2.exe

file3.exe

Move a folder to c:

i was thinking of doing a batch file which does this but the batch file executes all the programs at once.

I know there is a program called installshield which creates a setup file but it is expensive. I need some advice in what open source software can be used to do this work, i was thinking visual basic?

Comment: Check out: [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: If you want to do it *properly* rather than annoy users, take your time. It's not that easy. For starters, the install location shouldn't be hardcoded and there should be an uninstallation command. If any step fails, the setup as a whole should rollback rather than leave a dozen half-filled folders and orphaned registry entries behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), I think that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Look this application: http://www.sminstall.com/